# Guide to break this Sql code in subprocesses

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a sql query which reads as below

```
select * 
FROM   Table1 
       LEFT JOIN Table2 
              ON Table1.id = 
                 Table2.action_id 

       LEFT JOIN Table3 
              ON Table1.changeset_id = 
                 Table3.id 

       LEFT JOIN Table4 
              ON Table2.field_id = 
                 table4.id
```

I seek help to understand what will be going to happen in this code after completion. I understand the first part i.e.

```
select * 
    FROM   Table1 
           LEFT JOIN Table2 
                  ON Table1.id = 
                     Table2.action_id
```

*This I understand as join `Table1` and `Table2` based on `id (Table1)` and `action.id(Table2)` and after joining consider only those rows which have entries in `id(Table1)` by means of `LEFT JOIN`.*

But then am lost. What is the significance of next two `LEFT JOIN`?

How can I properly break this entire code into sub-processes to understand flow of execution process? Apology if my question is too trivial

Comment: We want to return rows from t3 which correspond with t1, regardless of whether there are rows which correspond between t1 and t2. The simplest way to see the effect (and quicker even than asking here), is to build simple sample tables, and, er, join them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a series of `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 
     ON Table1.id = Table2.action_id LEFT JOIN
     Table3 
     ON Table1.changeset_id = Table3.id LEFT JOIN
     Table4 
     ON Table2.field_id = table4.id
```

What this does is keep all rows in `Table1`, regardless of the matches in the subsequent tables.

Which rows match then follows the `ON` conditions.  This is simple if they only refer to the first table and the given table.  In your case, they also refer to intermediate tables.

So:

- For `Table2` you get columns for all rows that match `Table1`
- For `Table3` you get columns for all rows that match `Table1`
- For `Table4` you get columns for all rows in `Table4` that match rows in `Table2` that match rows in `Table1`.

I find that this is a little more complicated to explain than understand.  The key is that `NULL` values (which are missing values in outer joins) do not match the `ON` conditions.

Comment: Your explanation made me easier to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.changeset_id = Table3.id will add data for each row from Table3 only if Table1.changeset_id exists in Table3.id.

LEFT JOIN Table4 ON Table2.field_id = table4.id will add data for each row from Table4 only if Table2.field_id exists in Table4.id. If there is no match in the Table2 LEFT JOIN, you can be sure there is no match for this JOIN too.

When the left join can not be resolved, you will have all the column of the table with NULL value.

Did I understand the question correctly or was there something more complex?

Comment: So in your 1st statement line, we are joining T3 to which table? T1?

Comment: Yes the equality is between T1.changeset_id and T3.id so we take all the records in T1 and we try to add data from T3 if it's possible. If not, it will add NULL value for each column of T3 table